# How can I capture user IP address and store them automatically to my database?

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

am currently running an open voting system with no login form.
I wanted to restrict double voting using user IP Addresses, how can I record user addresses direct to my database and use them to restrict double voting?

Comment: Keep in mind that some ISPs, such as AOL, do not tie an IP to a specific user -- one user could show up at a different IP and, vice versa, two users could come from the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

The webserver exposes it as a variable to PHP like this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/ddg#3003233). PHP can then use that to insert into the database.

Given the scale of NAT usage as one of the factors where legitimate two votes from same IP could occur, I suggest setting a cookie on the browser as an anti-duplicate mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, may you help me with the cookies code.. I would like the block the already voted voter for 7days after casting vote

Comment: I have two pages, home.php, and submit_ballot.php page see https://github.com/magotech/Open-Online-Voting-System

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/ is a forum for asking application programming like questions (which is where this question should of been asked), but I suggest trying yourself before asking (its a help site only). Look up how to do SQL joins, your code needs it.